# Best Practice For Multiple Usage Of UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a main UICollectionView with custom UICollectionViewCells. And I use it in multiple UIViewControllers.

I have a timeline, likes, profile which use same UICollectionView.

What is the best practice of declaring UICollectionView with this kind of situations?

I tried to create a class named MainProductCollectionView which inherits from UIViewController. And in TimeLineViewController I use it like below.

```
let vc = MainProductCollectionView() //init
self.view.addSubview(vc.collectionView)
```

But I'm not sure if it is best way to use. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

There are 2 solutions:

- Create a custom collectionView that inherit from `UICollectionView` and contains all the delegate methods like `celForItemAtIndexPath` `numberOfItemsInSection` ...

Or

- Create your collectionViewCell in a `xib` file and then use     `yourCollectionView.register(cellType: CustomCell.self)`

Comment: But in both solutions, I have to write same web requests. This may occur code duplication.